# Long time to first byte for static content

Tags: performance, iis7

I have large time to first byte for static content on IIS 7.5, it's not site specific it's slow for all sites on that server. Web.config setting runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests is set to false, and gzip is enabled for static content. How can I troubleshoot this problem ?

Here are the timings, time to first byte for fairly complex ASP.NET site is 368 ms, and for just grabing css file is 617 ms !! That time is different every time but still too much, not below 200 ms that seems way too much for such task.

Server has plenty free memory (in this moment more than 7 GB).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are all your images compressed as much as possible? Are you using css sprites? Have you minified your css and javascript files? In your screen shot I see a .hr domain. You should run a traceroute to see if there is a problem in between your website and you. If so you should test it's performance on another server.

Comment: I don't see how image compression, css sprites, and minified js can affect time to first byte, IIS just have to serve file content whatever that be

Comment: I will accept this answer since problem is clearly not on my server, when you mention traceroute I conected with RD directly and run test on server, and time to first byte is very good (up to max 0.1 sec)